# Stop students deactivating wifi F2

Tags: wireless-networking, keyboard, domain

I have 20 Novatech nFinity laptops that the students use in classes. Some of the kids like to use Fn+F2 to disable the wireless and then log off, so the machine can't then connect to the domain, and I've got find which ones are affected, log in locally and re-enable (resulting in disruption for the following class).

Is there a way to deactivate this function on the keyboard (short of ripping the button out from under the Fn key of each laptop)?

Comment: You first have to determine if you have software installed that is doing this or if its a feature of the hardware itself.

Comment: Which laptop model?

Comment: @miroxlav Novatech nFinity ? ;)

Comment: Short of trying a couple of things it is hard to suggest.. Sometimes the Fn key and Num Lock disables the Fn keys but easy to get around. You can sometimes disable them in the bios depending on the bios. Otherwise get your Admins to lock down the machines more so that the ability to disable a network adapter is not allowed for a standard user...

Comment: Take one laptop and try uninstall its Novatech driver for hotkeys. Not sure if there is any but some for example, Dell computers have keyboard driver which causes Fn+Key conbinations to work. Uninstalling it can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so I got in touch with Novatech and they advised me that there is a piece of software called "Photkey" that controlled *all* of the Fn hotkeys. Deleting this from add/remove programs on each laptop and hiding the system tray icon using Group Policy will be the solution, and it seems to have worked on a test machine, however I'll need to see if the kids can figure out a workaround.

Comment: The only way they'll figure out a workaround is if they can install the software again (or do you mean disconnect the wireless using another method? Either can be prevented with the correct security settings.)

Comment: I'm not ruling anything out, they're locked down as tight as possible, but I wouldn't put it past them figuring out how to use kon-boot or similar. They might be annoying, but they're also persistent and bright.

Comment: If someone is willing to go to *those* lengths to turn off WiFi I'd be more concerned about why they are so insistent and what exactly they are being forced to do that they don't want to.

Comment: GCSE revision...

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look in the Bios/EFI, most laptops allow you to customise the shortcut keys and disable them.

I'm not sure what this machine's base model is so I can't look at this in detail for you, but, if you bought 20 - I would ask them for assistance as well.

Comment: sadly the BIOS for this machine is really basic and doesn't offer any options for keyboard customisation

Comment: @DeadlyWonky - Hi, my contact details are in my profile, if you get a chance, can you get in contact with me? I wouldn't mind talking to you if you have a second... about education IT.